# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, fake-proofs

I am trying to prove the integral test for series, but got a strange result.

Assume that $f$ is decreasing and positive.

Because the series can be imagined as the area-sum of $1$-wide rectangles of height $f_n$ and each of those rectangles can be expressed as a constant integral on a $1$-wide interval where $f_n=f(n)$ is the constant when integrating $dx$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}f(n)\,dx$$

Instead of $f(n)$ we can use the function value $f(x)$ from either end of the 1-wide interval so either floor or ceiling of $x.$

If we use the floor then the height is the left of the interval in this case always $n.$

If we use the ceiling then the height is the right of the interval in this case always $n+1$ so we should start from $n=0$ not $n=1$ to get the same sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}f(\lceil x\rceil)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1} f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\, dx$$

Obviously, $$a_1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}.$$

Therefore, we have

$$f(1) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} f(\lceil x\rceil)\, dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\, dx.$$

Since we have a function of $x$, we can concatenate the sum of integrals into a single integral:

$$f(1) + \int_1^\infty f(\lceil x\rceil)\, dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = \int_1^\infty f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\, dx$$

Because $f$ is decreasing we know that $f(\lceil x\rceil)\leq f(x)\leq f(\lfloor x\rfloor),$ therefore

$$f(1) + \int_1^\infty f(x)\, dx \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n \leq \int_1^\infty f(x)\, dx$$

$$f(1) + \int_1^\infty f(x)\, dx \leq \int_1^\infty f(x)\, dx$$

$$f(1) + A \leq A$$

What happened? $f$ was positive!

Comment: As it stands, it is very difficult to understand what your post is asking. I will fix what I can. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Please take a look and be sure that it says what you intended.

Comment: I am using all the possible unicode characters. I think it is readable. Why aren't unicode characters rendered prettier? Why are you using that Tex/MathJax stuff? It is an ugly mess and it has to be learned, while unicode is obvious.

Comment: @user1358: Based on my experience in the math community, I'm afraid that your opinion is a very small minority.

Comment: This is what I meant, thanks.

Comment: @user1358: It was readable, insofar as I was relatively certain what you were trying to say, but as you noted, the rendering was very ugly. Many Unicode characters will, in fact, render, if you put them inside `$ $`, but not all work out as you would expect. For example, `$∫ n→(n+1) f(n) dx$` yields $∫ n→(n+1) f(n) dx.$ To fix it, use `$∫_n^{n+1} f(n) dx$` instead, to get $∫_n^{n+1} f(n) dx,$ or use `$\int_n^{n+1} f(n) dx$` instead of any Unicode.

Comment: the _ and ^ does make sense, thanks

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you went wrong when you introduced the inequality at the very end. Indeed, $f(\lceil x\rceil)\le f(x)$ since $f$ is decreasing, so since $$f(1) + \int_1^\infty f(\lceil x\rceil)\, dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$$ then $$f(1) + \int_1^\infty f(x)\, dx\geq f(1) + \int_1^\infty f(\lceil x\rceil)\, dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n.$$ Also, since $f(x)\le f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = \int_1^\infty f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\, dx,$$ then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = \int_1^\infty f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\, dx\ge\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx.$$

You absolutely had the right idea. You just misapplied the inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n$. You state correctly that $f(1)+U=S=V$, where
$$U=\int_1^\infty f(\lceil x\rceil)\,\mathrm dx,\qquad V= \int_1^\infty f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\,\mathrm dx,$$
and you then note correctly that, the function $f$ being nonincreasing, $f(\lceil x\rceil)\leqslant f(x)\leqslant f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ for every $x$. So far, so good.

But the conclusion of all this is that
$$
U\leqslant\int_1^\infty f(x)\, \mathrm dx\leqslant V,
$$
thus,
$$
\int_1^\infty f(x)\, \mathrm dx\leqslant V=S=f(1)+U\leqslant f(1)+\int_1^\infty f(x)\, \mathrm dx,
$$
not the other way round.

Comment: Thanks. I can only accept one, so I added a +1 for yours.